# return indices if unit repeats in the array

Tags: javascript

I want the repeated indices of each unit in the sorted array below.

unit **39** is repeated from **index 1** to **index 3** right?

```
const array = [

  {
    unit: 38,
  },
  
  {
    unit: 39,
  },

  {
    unit: 39,
  },
  
  {
    unit: 39,
  },
  
  {
    unit: 40,
  },
  
  {
    unit: 41,
  },
  
  {
    unit: 41,
  },
  
  {
    unit: 42,
  },
]
```

So the desired result would be:

```
[
  {
    unit: 39,
    fromIndex: 1,
    toIndex: 3,
  },
  
  {
    unit: 41,
    fromIndex: 5,
    toIndex: 6,
  },
]
```

I tried to remmeber the index of each pair of the units but this idea is not working with more than two repetations . so I need a handI think

```
let u;

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

  const a = array[i];
  const b = array[i + 1] || {
    unit: null
  };

  if (a.unit == b.unit) {
    u = a.unit; // remmeber the repeated unit here
    ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array reduce and filter methods:

```
const result = array.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  if (index > 0 && array[index - 1].unit === item.unit) {
    const last = acc[acc.length - 1];
    last.toIndex = index;
  } else {
    acc.push({
      unit: item.unit,
      fromIndex: index,
      toIndex: index
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []).filter(item => item.fromIndex !== item.toIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the lat item or in the result the last item.

```js
const
    array = [{ unit: 38 }, { unit: 39 }, { unit: 39 }, { unit: 39 }, { unit: 40 }, { unit: 41 }, { unit: 41 }, { unit: 42 }],
    result = array.reduce((r, { unit }, i, a) => {
        if (unit !== a[i - 1]?.unit) return r;
        if (unit !== r[r.length - 1]?.unit) r.push({ unit, fromIndex: i - 1, toIndex: i });
        else r[r.length - 1].toIndex = i;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what is `at` it makes an error in node.js!!!!

Comment: [`Array#at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) is an accessor of the array. and very helpful for getting an element from the end. you could replace `.at(-1)` with `[r.length - 1]` in this case.

Comment: could you please change it yourself I get duplicate result...